# If I want a form input to be hidden, can I use CSS display: none or do I need to use an input type=hidden?

Tags: html, forms

I have a long form and depending on certain parameters, some fields may be hidden.  I can either write this pseudocode:

```
if(input is hidden) {
  <input type="hidden" ... />
}
else {
  <input type="text" ... />
}
```

Or I could simply apply a style with `display:none` for the fields that I want to be hidden.

The latter is easier, but is there a reason why I would want to use `type="hidden"` input fields rather than invisible regular fields?  Is the only issue that people without CSS would see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you are filtering output based on some condition such as a logged in user. If this is the case then go for the code in your pseudocode option such like

```
if($var=='loggedin'):
    <input type="text" name="privateFieldName" />
else:
    //do not display the field
endif;
```

If you simply want a hidden field regardless use the html hidden input element